# what does this error mean ? Can't process transaction with signature from scripted account. I'm using RIDE on Waves platform

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I'm using RIDE language to write my code but I did not get it what is the problem exactly? did i do anything wrong?

```
'error': 112, 
    'message': "State check failed. Reason: Can't process transaction with signature from scripted account", 
    'tx': {'type': 4, 'id': '8nffuSs3CQa9v3eYQZYnBwQRwMWH5VausqkKipQoCHtd', 'sender': '3XcE4knb13yyXKpdNvWhwvjrYsgMXsoicQM', 
    'senderPublicKey': '8EksPcCrjotLsCPD3aw2ciHqq3JQ5va7JLpBTjjfSJ47', 
    'fee': 500000000, 
    'timestamp': 1551372704969, 
    'signature': '766mrSP811i8x3P1fqPvMDosF7pD7Sfx7dQq2csCzjttPDQ6S75jWDFP924uLmRsSKtBkNcqnyjQsdQen3En1KQ', 
    'proofs': ['766mrSP811i8x3P1fqPvMDosF7pD7Sfx7dQq2csCzjttPDQ6S75jWDFP924uLmRsSKtBkNcqnyjQsdQen3En1KQ'], 
    'version': 1, 
    'recipient': '3XrUtvRZ6LLU8F2wwkuDffwTuLUNcpnjthB', 
    'assetId': None, 
    'feeAssetId': None, 
    'feeAsset': None, 
    'amount': 1000, 
    'attachment': ''}}
```

Anyone ever seen such an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you're using transaction version 1 as it's showed 'version': 1 , 
you should specify the version as 'version': 2.
There is 'version': 1, but scripted accounts work with 'version': 2.
you can check the [transactions versions](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-environment/waves-protocol/versioned-transactions.html) for more details.